# Custom Image Dialog layout

Tags: android, android-layout, android-imageview

> **Requirement**

I want to show an image in custom dialog with border and close button, and `ImageView` is `TouchImageView` for zoom in/out feature. like this

https://i.stack.imgur.com/nN1jJ.jpg

> **I Tried**

I have tried many ways for a border but didn't get the solution.

My code

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <com.android.example.view.TouchImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageSingleImage"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:src="@mipmap/ic_launcher" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

> Using @user2025187 code i got this in output

https://i.stack.imgur.com/Cv6Ph.png

> I am clicking on this image

https://i.stack.imgur.com/LA8Uc.png

Comment: already border effect on your image. what's the problem?

Comment: i want that type of dialog

Answer (score 1):

This is a simple thing you can search it on google also.

create a layout file in drawable folder and add below code as rectangle.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<solid android:color="#FFFFFF" />
<stroke android:width="1dp" android:color="#000000" />
<padding android:left="1dp" android:top="1dp" android:right="1dp"
android:bottom="1dp" />
```

create a layout file and add this xml. ex -dialog.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" >

<com.android.example.view.TouchImageView
    android:id="@+id/imageDialog"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginRight="6dp" 
    android:background="@drawable/rectangle"/>

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textDialog"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textColor="#FFF"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/imageDialog"/>

 <Button
    android:id="@+id/declineButton"
    android:layout_width="100px"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text=" Submit "
    android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
    android:layout_below="@+id/textDialog"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/imageDialog"
    />

  </RelativeLayout>
```

add below code in your java file and your dialog is ready.

```
          final Dialog dialog = new Dialog(CustomDialog.this);
            // Include dialog.xml file
            dialog.setContentView(R.layout.dialog);
            // Set dialog title
            dialog.setTitle("Custom Dialog");

            // set values for custom dialog components - text, image and button
            TextView text = (TextView) dialog.findViewById(R.id.textDialog);
            text.setText("Custom dialog Android example.");
            ImageView image = (ImageView) dialog.findViewById(R.id.imageDialog);
            image.setImageResource(R.drawable.image0);

            dialog.show();

            Button declineButton = (Button) dialog.findViewById(R.id.declineButton);
            // if decline button is clicked, close the custom dialog
            declineButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    // Close dialog
                    dialog.dismiss();
                }
            });
```

Comment: I don't want to know how to make custom dialog, I know very well. But my problem is I want border outside of imageview and it should be flexible.

Comment: border is not for imageview, it is for dailog

Comment: @PatelPinkal you want border on image view or on dialog

Comment: android:background="@drawable/rectangle"
add this to your main layout or add this background on runtime on your dialog, if you want border on  your dialog

Comment: you can apply border on imageview or dialog, but my imageView is custom with zoom. whenever i try to set border to image view it set fix hight and width which image have but i want in full screen. and whenever  i apply border to dialog it will conatin extra space because some image hight is big or in some width

Comment: goto paint and add border to your image this is the simplest solution.
otherwise add background in your TouchImageView class file according to your need

Answer (score 1):

Try this,

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
      android:layout_width="fill_parent"
      android:layout_height="fill_parent"
      android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
      android:layout_centerVertical="true"
      android:layout_margin="10dp">

<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:layout_margin="10dp"
    android:background="@color/colorWhite">

    <com.android.example.view.TouchImageView
        android:id="@+id/iv_imageSingleImage"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        android:contentDescription="@string/contentDescription"
        android:padding="5dp" />

</RelativeLayout>

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/iv_close"
    android:layout_width="30dp"
    android:layout_height="30dp"
    android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:src="@drawable/ic_cross" />
</RelativeLayout>
```